# Aggregating arrays of data in mongodb

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to check consecutive value of certain items inside a number of arrays in nodejs is there any aggregation technique that can help.
suppose i have 5 objects in an array and each object has cetain parameter such as

```
var arr = [{name: abc,age:10},
{name: gtt,age:12},
{name: sss,age:13},
{name: dddttt,age:14},
{name: abc,age:4} ]
```

now i want to check that in each object the age is less than 10.what i can do is loop through the array and check every condition and make count or push value. but i want to know is there any technique

Comment: Tell us what have you tried so far?

Comment: i havenot tried any thing so far. i am looping through the arrays check condition for age grater than 5 and if true i am pushing it into new array and at last i am getting array.lenth property to know  how many peple are greater than age 5

Comment: Please show your code here.

Comment: Is that array a result of Mongoose query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly you should $unwind, it will occur, each item of array is seperate object, later;

```
{$match: {"$age": {$lt: 10}}}
```